# EditText does not show the keyboard, even when touched

Tags: android

I am trying to make a DialogFragment that dynamically adds EditTexts to a RecyclerView as the user enters text in the fields. I am having trouble with something that should be quite easy.

I have the two initial EditText boxes I want, one has focus, one cannot gain focus yet. However, the keyboard never shows up. I can tap on the EditText to paste text, but nothing I do can get the keyboard to show up.

I am using a custom ArrayViewAdapter which extends RecyclerView.Adapter to place the EditText field in it's own Linear Layout.

Here is relevant code:

layout_linear.xml --> layout file for RecyclerView items

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ll"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1">
</LinearLayout>
```

ArrayViewAdapter:

```
class ArrayViewAdapter<E>(val data: ArrayList<E>, c: Context) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<ArrayViewAdapter.ViewHolder>() where E : View {
...
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.layout_linear, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(view)
}
...
class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    // The ID of the TableLayout
    val ll = itemView.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.ll)

    fun bind(v : View) {
        ll.addView(v)
        ll.clearFocus()
    }
}
```

ListEntryDialog:

```
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    val view = activity.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_entry_dialog, null)
...
val ed1 = EditText(activity)
    //ed1.addTextChangedListener(dw)
    ed1.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    ed1.requestFocus()
val ed2 = EditText(activity)

    //ed2.addTextChangedListener(dw)
    ed2.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    ed2.isFocusableInTouchMode = false
    ed2.isFocusable = false

    fields.add(ed1)
    fields.add(ed2)

    adapter = ArrayViewAdapter(fields, activity)
    rv.adapter = adapter
...
val builder = AlertDialog.Builder()
return builder.create()
```

the xml file for the dialog:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:name="com.github.jlcarveth.grocer.layout.fragment.ListEntryDialog"
tools:context="com.github.jlcarveth.grocer.layout.fragment.ListEntryDialog">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/led_title"
        android:text="TITLE"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/led_rv"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Why won't the keyboard show up?

Comment: did you make sure to show the keyboard? emulators can have that setting off.

Comment: I am running it on my Pixel 2. I can get keyboards to show up where I use EditTexts elsewhere.

Comment: Can anyone answer thiis?

Answer (score 0):

Recyclerview seems to take focus away from the editText. This could work for you.

```
recyclerView.descendantFocusability = FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS
```